# How to separate out view modifiers into callable/includable structs

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a case where a particular view modifier is used throughout a view. Instead of repeating this code over and over again, is it possible to make it callable? The .foreground modifier has no context by itself as it is not standalone syntax.....

```
struct ColorTheme: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        .foregroundColor( ((userSettings.mapType == "Satellite") ||  Error: Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'foregroundColor'
            (userSettings.mapType == "Hybrid") ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "AssassinsCreed") ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Aubergine")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Dark")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "MidnightCommand")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Night")) ? Color(UIColor.white) : Color(UIColor.black))
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `make it callable`? It is already a function `View.foregroundColor()`, so callable. Would you clarify?

Comment: I was referring to this: func darkTheme() -> Bool {
        
        if ((userSettings.mapType == "Satellite") ||
            (userSettings.mapType == "Hybrid") ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "AssassinsC`reed") ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Aubergine")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Dark")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "MidnightCommand")  ||
            (userSettings.mapStyle == "Night")) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

Comment: The original question was how can I separate out .foreground... into separate callable view....one file has Text("...") other file has .foreground(....)

Comment: @Tim Could you provide your *expected* result? Even in pseudo-code. I don't think I understand what you need.

Comment: @pawello2222, I will create something and add here in a bit...sorry for the confusion...and I do appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var mapType: String = "Satellite"
    
    var fgColor: Color {
        switch mapType {
        case "Satellite", "Hybrid", "AssassinsCreed", "Aubergine", "Dark", "MidnightCommand", "Night":
            return Color(UIColor.white)
        default:
            return Color(UIColor.black)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ColorTheme: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
            .foregroundColor(userSettings.fgColor)
    }
}
```

You may also consider making `mapType` an *enum*.

---

**EDIT**

You may be looking for a View extension:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func customFgColor(mapType: String) -> some View {
        switch mapType {
        case "Satellite", "Hybrid", "AssassinsCreed", "Aubergine", "Dark", "MidnightCommand", "Night":
            return self.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.white))
        default:
            return self.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.black))
        }
    }
}

struct ColorTheme: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
            .customFgColor(mapType: userSettings.mapType)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar by putting logic for the mapType in a separate function. The issue was that if I don't have an actual reference to the userSettings fields in main view, they do not get updated. I had to move that logic back to main view to get all updates. I will play around with your idea to see what I find. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I got it to work correctly by including the separate function in the main view.I shortened the code from to this .foregroundColor(darkTheme() ? Color(UIColor.white) : Color(UIColor.black)). This still doesn't solve the original question of is it possible use include like behavior in swiftui? How can I break up the markup language across files?

Comment: @Tim I think I figured out what you need. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I think that is the answer...so essentially you have a "callable" view modifier via the extension. Thank you for the help!